# Download a backup of the files directory

Tags: 7, files

I've researched this a little bit, but I'm wondering if anyone else has an idea on how to do this. The request is to be able to create a weekly archive of the files uploaded through a document content type, basically downloading all files. The client is a team of non-technical, financial advisors - so the simpler, the better.

Obviously Backup & Migrate doesn't fit the bill since that's database only. The only thing I can really think of is writing a bash script to gzip their document folder, and then have a continually updating URL based on a date that links to that zipped folder.

Comment: `rsync` is usually the best tool for a job like this

Comment: Right, we were just looking for something that would be more client friendly and wasn't going to cost them a fortune for us to custom build.

Comment: It depends on their local setup of course, but a one line rsync on a cron job to sync the files folder locally should be straightforward to set up on windows/mac (and linux obviously, but clients never seem to be on linux). Might be more straightforward then testing other modules or script based solutions is all I mean

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server management, not Drupal itself.

Comment: I disagree. The client wants to be able to download all documents uploaded through a document content type. They are financial advisors, not developers. They have no idea what rsync is, nor do they care. They want a button to click in Drupal that will download all files uploaded in a week. That's definitely Drupal, not server management.

Comment: Why would your client need to know what rsync is? Can't you write the script for them? It's literally one line

Comment: Could you give an example as an answer? I feel like I'm thinking about your solution differently.

Comment: I'm probably making a big assumption actually - are you in a position to install a script and set up a scheduled job on your client's machines (preferably servers) for them? If not then ignore me ;)

Comment: Disagree that this is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually [Backup and Migrate Files](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_files) too.

Comment: I'd prefer something that isn't in dev for a client site, but I'll check it out.

Comment: After multiple conversations, this seems to be the best way to go so far in terms of requirements for our client. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Weate using cdn, having the files folder, nor really in the server but linked to it from the server. You could use this idea to have the files in drop box or any similar service, and mounted in your server.

As it is Dropbox, it will be sync directly with any other folder, like your customerfor example.

Comment: That is actually a pretty creative idea, but I think that puts too much power into the client's hands. I know it's their site, but let's face it - they delete something in Dropbox and then a file doesn't load on their site, I know who they're calling to fix it. I will keep this in my back pocket though, thanks for sharing.

Comment: I am sure you can find a similar service in which the client has no access to shared folders, just read. Have a look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/371530/is-there-a-way-to-make-dropbox-public-folders-read-only